# Use variable for case statement mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
select 
count(so.shop_order_id),
case
    when so.subtotal_amount < 99.99 then 'under 100'
    when so.subtotal_amount between 100.00 and 149.99 then '100-149' 
    when so.subtotal_amount between 150.00 and 249.99 then '150-249'
    when so.subtotal_amount between 250.00 and 399.99 then '250-399' 
    when so.subtotal_amount between 400.00 and 499.99 then '400-499'
    when so.subtotal_amount > 500 then '500+'
end

from shop_order so

where so.created_at between '2015-11-29 23:59:59' and '2015-11-31 00:00:01'
and  (case
    when so.subtotal_amount < 99.99 then 'under 100'
    when so.subtotal_amount between 100.00 and 149.99 then '100-149' 
    when so.subtotal_amount between 150.00 and 249.99 then '150-249'
    when so.subtotal_amount between 250.00 and 399.99 then '250-399' 
    when so.subtotal_amount between 400.00 and 499.99 then '400-499'
    when so.subtotal_amount > 500 then '500+'
end) is not null

group by (case
    when so.subtotal_amount < 99.99 then 'under 100'
    when so.subtotal_amount between 100.00 and 149.99 then '100-149' 
    when so.subtotal_amount between 150.00 and 249.99 then '150-249'
    when so.subtotal_amount between 250.00 and 399.99 then '250-399' 
    when so.subtotal_amount between 400.00 and 499.99 then '400-499'
    when so.subtotal_amount > 500 then '500+'
end)
```

It works well for me, but I would like to know if there is a way to NOT have to repeat that case statement. Can I set a variable or use an alias or something to stand in its place? I have to edit every instance of the case statement every time I make a tweak. I'm open to anything. Thanks.

Comment: With MySQL you can use an alias from the SELECT expressions in the GROUP BY, but not in the WHERE; but using that CASE in the where is overkill, just do `AND so.subtotal_amount IS NOT NULL` _(as it is the only way, short of worrying about values like 99.999, the CASE could result in null)_, or add `HAVING theAlias IS NOT NULL` to the query.
...actually, you have a "hole" in your logic at the subtotal_amount = 500.

Comment: Excellent feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the implementation of what @Uueerdo wrote in the comment.

Use an alias for your expression in the SELECT clause (`as range`). GROUP BY using that alias `group by range`. The expression can only be NULL if `so.subtotal_amount IS NULL`, so you can use this condition in the WHERE clause.

Your expression can also be shortened up. If the first condition (`subtotal_amount < 100`) fails, then it's clear that `subtotal_amount` is  `>= 100` so you don't need a BETWEEN statement. Note that `BETWEEN` means "including" in MySQL. `x BETWEEN a and b` is the same as `x >= a and x <= b`.

Also - when you "say" 'under 100' you should use `< 100` instead of `< 99.99`. Same for '500+' - it should be `>= 500`. So you don't have any gaps in your ranges.

```
select 
    count(so.shop_order_id),
    case
        when so.subtotal_amount <  100 then 'under 100'
        when so.subtotal_amount <  150 then '100-149' 
        when so.subtotal_amount <  250 then '150-249'
        when so.subtotal_amount <  400 then '250-399' 
        when so.subtotal_amount <  500 then '400-499'
        when so.subtotal_amount >= 500 then '500+'
    end as range
from shop_order so
where so.created_at between '2015-11-29 23:59:59' and '2015-11-31 00:00:01'
  and so.subtotal_amount is not null
group by range
```

Comment: This looks brilliant. Thanks for the explanation and taking time to look through this. This will definitely save me some time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
select count(so.shop_order_id), so.thecase
from (
  select
    *,
    case
      when subtotal_amount < 99.99 then 'under 100'
      when subtotal_amount between 100.00 and 149.99 then '100-149' 
      when subtotal_amount between 150.00 and 249.99 then '150-249'
      when subtotal_amount between 250.00 and 399.99 then '250-399' 
      when subtotal_amount between 400.00 and 499.99 then '400-499'
      when subtotal_amount > 500 then '500+'
    end AS thecase
  from shop_order
) so
where
  so.created_at between '2015-11-29 23:59:59' and '2015-11-31 00:00:01'
  and so.thecase is not null
group by
  so.thecase
```

Comment: This is interesting, and runs well in this instance as I am dealing with a small number of records, but would this be worth it with larger amounts of data. Sub-queries slow things down quite a bit right?